# Does anyone know how a System.Windows.Forms.Timer affects the host application and the system in general?

Tags: c#, timer, cpu-usage

Does anyone know how a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` affects the host application and the system in general?

A threaded background loop on one hand has a very high CPU usage %, whilst a `Timer` with a very high tick rate shows no effect in Windows Task Manager.

Does a high tick-rate timer clutter up the Windows Message loop, or?

Answer (score 3):

Define "high tick rate timer" :).

The problem with timer components relying on WM_TIMER (such as the Windows.Forms one) is manifold:

- You will *not* be able to get a resolution better than 50 msec out of it, ever.
- If your system is under load (e.g. heavy redrawing, running over RDP links, etc.) you might get WM_TIMER messages once every 500 msec or more, no matter how low you've set the interval.
- WM_TIMER messages are synthetic messages and might not get delivered to your application at all for prolonged periods of time if your message queue gets flooded with other messages.
- If your timer method takes longer than one timer interval to execute, the timer will "skip" the message, i.e. you will not get another WM_TIMER message until you've returned from the first one. In other words, you will never get two WM_TIMER messages one after the other in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Overall I have not noticed many negative downfalls to using a timer component inside my application, they are much more effective, and better on resources than some other methods out there.

I find that this [Timer Comparison](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) article from microsoft is also helpful when comparing these types of things.

But the long and short of it is that they don't appear to clutter up much.